# EventChannel.EventSink is always null in Native Android with flutter

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I am trying to integrate native `android` code in my `flutter` app. I have service class which get user's location. Now this location update will be continuous and the location will be send from my `service` class to `MainActivity` via callback method called `onLocationUpdated`

Now in my `MainActivity.kt`

```
class MainActivity : FlutterFragmentActivity(),LocationCallback {
   private val networkEventChannel = "com.example.locationconnectivity"
    private var attachEvent: EventChannel.EventSink? = null

   override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
       

        EventChannel(
            flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger,
            networkEventChannel
        ).setStreamHandler(
            object : EventChannel.StreamHandler {
                override fun onListen(args: Any, events: EventChannel.EventSink) {
                    Log.w("TAG_NAME", "Adding listener")
                    attachEvent = events


                }

                override fun onCancel(args: Any) {
                    Log.w("TAG_NAME", "Cancelling listener")
                    attachEvent = null
                    println("StreamHandler - onCanceled: ")
                }
            }
        )
      .....
}

 override fun onLocationUpdated(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
        runOnUiThread {
            Log.i("attacheventis", "${attachEvent}",)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Lat lng ${latitude} ${longitude}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    attachEvent?.success("${latitude} ${longitude}")

        }
    }
}
```

Now when I call `attachEvent?.success` in `onLocationUpdated` I always get `attachEvent` as null and `onListen` and `onCancel` are never called in `configureFlutterEngine`

Also I don't want to create separate class for `EventChannel`. Need to handle everything in `MainActivity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is insane. The error was because I forgot to add `?` to `args: Any` in my kotlin code. Something like below

```
override fun onListen(args: Any?, events: EventChannel.EventSink) {
```

Comment: I have edited my answer to explain why you had to apply this particular fix. Let me know if the explanation I have included in my answer makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The `onListen` callback in your Android `MainActivity` is called when the Flutter side starts listening to the event stream. Similarly, `onCancel` is called when Flutter stops listening to the event stream. If neither of these methods is being called, it is likely because there is no Flutter code that is attempting to listen to or cancel the stream.
See also "**[Event Channel in Flutter](https://mobikul.com/event-channel-in-flutter/)**" from [Rishabh Sharma](https://twitter.com/rishabhsharma10).

On the Flutter side, you will need to use the [`EventChannel`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/EventChannel-class.html) to listen to the events emitted by the Android side.

Create (in your Flutter widget with Dart) an instance of the `EventChannel` with the same name as you defined in the Android side, and listen to the stream of events:

```dart
const eventChannel = EventChannel('com.example.locationconnectivity');

StreamSubscription? subscription;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  subscription = eventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream().listen(
    (dynamic event) {
      print('Received: $event');
      // Handle the received location here
    },
    onError: (dynamic error) {
      print('Received error: ${error.message}');
    },
  );
}

@override
void dispose() {
  subscription?.cancel();
  super.dispose();
}
```

That code on the Flutter/Dart side would be enough for your code on the Android side to have a non-null `EventChannel.EventSink`.

---

from [your code](https://github.com/kyadalu1/fluttereventchannel), if you do not see the Kotlin [`android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/flutapp/MainActivity.kt` "Adding listener"](https://github.com/kyadalu1/fluttereventchannel/blob/7304baa685aab334502e9576ba5f1819db9ef7ee/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/flutapp/MainActivity.kt#L114C40-L114C55) log trace, it suggests that the Dart side is not initiating the connection to the `EventChannel` properly, or the bridge between Flutter's Dart code and native code has some issue.

First, make sure the Dart side logic is being executed. Add a print statement right before you start listening to the `EventChannel` in your [`lib/main.dart`](https://github.com/kyadalu1/fluttereventchannel/blob/7304baa685aab334502e9576ba5f1819db9ef7ee/lib/main.dart#L57).

```dart
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("Dart side: Initializing EventChannel listener...");
    
    subscription = _eventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream().listen(
    (dynamic event) {
        print('FlutterReceived: $event');
    },
    onError: (dynamic error) {
        print('Received error: ${error.message}');
    },
    );
}
```

You can also try, just to get more detail from any error:

```dart
    onError: (Object obj, StackTrace stackTrace) {
      print(obj);
      print(stackTrace);
    },
```

Check your Flutter logs (via the terminal or console where you run your Flutter app) to make sure this print statement is being executed.
And do so after a full stop/retart of the application: no hot-reload.
And preferably a full rebuild first (`flutter clean` + `flutter run`)

Run [`flutter doctor`](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows#run-flutter-doctor) to check if there are any issues with your Flutter setup.

---

> The error was because I forgot to add `?` to `args: Any` in my kotlin code. Something like below
>
> ```
> override fun onListen(args: Any?, events: EventChannel.EventSink) {
> ```

The reason for adding `?` to `args: Any?` in Kotlin pertains to [Kotlin's null safety feature](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html).

In Kotlin, by design, [every type is non-nullable](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-nullability-guide.html#support-for-nullable-types). That means, by default, you cannot assign `null` to a variable or parameter unless you explicitly specify that the type is nullable. To make a type nullable in Kotlin, you append a `?` to the type declaration.

When working with `EventChannel.StreamHandler`, the `onListen` method has two parameters:

1. `args`: The arguments passed from Dart when initiating the event stream.
2. `events`: An `EventSink` object to send events back to the Dart side.

In many cases, no arguments are passed from Dart when initiating the event stream, so `args` would be `null`.

In Java, this is not an issue because all object types are nullable by default. However, in Kotlin, if you declare `args` as `Any` (non-nullable), and then Dart sends no arguments (which translates to `null` on the Kotlin side), it would result in a crash because you are effectively passing `null` to a non-nullable parameter.

By declaring `args` as `Any?`, you are telling Kotlin that this parameter can accept nullable values, including `null`.

The code compiles because of Kotlin's permissive behavior around Java interoperability. However, at runtime, Kotlin's strict null-safety checks kick in, leading to an error when trying to assign a null value to a non-nullable variable. That error prevents the event stream from being established correctly.

When the Dart side attempts to set up an event stream with the Android side, it does so through platform channels. If there is any error on the Android side during this setup (like a nullability violation causing an exception), the Dart side will interpret this as a failure to establish the stream. That is why you never see the "Adding listener" log.

The `args` parameter in the `onListen` method can often be null if no arguments are passed from Dart. If you define this parameter as non-nullable (`Any`) in Kotlin, and then Dart tries to establish the stream with a null `args`, the Kotlin side will throw an error, which stops the event stream setup process.

Comment: I still get null

Comment: @BraveEvidence Still null for `attachEvent`? Can you double-check the dart code I proposed in the answer is actually executed? (or the Kotlin `onListen` would never be executed). Double-check the channel name (which must be the same on both sides, Kotlin and Dart). Try a full restart of your Flutter app.

Comment: @BraveEvidence Thank you for that code. Do you see the ["`Adding listene`" log message](https://github.com/kyadalu1/fluttereventchannel/blob/7304baa685aab334502e9576ba5f1819db9ef7ee/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/flutapp/MainActivity.kt#L114C40-L114C55) in your logs?

Comment: No I can't see it

Comment: @BraveEvidence So that is the first step: make sure you can see that log, because as long as you do not see it, `attachEvent` will remain null. I have edited the answer to suggest some debugging avenues.

Comment: Still I don't see anything in the error callback